# android ndk lib don't install

Tags: android, android-ndk

```
AndroidManifest.xml
res/drawable-hdpi-v4/icon.png
res/drawable-ldpi-v4/icon.png
res/drawable-mdpi-v4/icon.png
res/layout/main.xml
resources.arsc
classes.dex
lib/x86_64/libnativehelper.so
lib/x86_64/libcootek_pte_oem.so
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/CERT.SF
META-INF/CERT.RSA
```

I use `aapt` to show my apk.
After I use `adb install`, my apk's lib directory on andriod emulator is empty. Why?

1. My apk is built use ABI x86_64
2. My android emulator is API 21 and x86_64.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason for your app's lib directory to be empty after installation.

Are you sure it's empty ? how do you get its path ? On my x86_64 emulator, libs are getting installed into `/data/app/packagename-N/lib/x86_64`